# Where is the documentation for admin.sleepBlocks?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

Sorry for being stupid.

```
> web3.version
{
  api: "0.20.1",
  ethereum: "0x41",
  network: "1108",
  node: "Geth/v1.9.21-stable-0287d548/windows-amd64/go1.15",
  whisper: undefined,
  getEthereum: function(callback),
  getNetwork: function(callback),
  getNode: function(callback),
  getWhisper: function(callback)
}
>
```

My web3 version is 0.20.1, but https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/0.20.7/DOCUMENTATION.md doesn't mention `admin.sleepBlocks` at all.

`admin.sleepBlocks(1)` returns true immediately on my private chain. This behavior doesn't agree with http://adam.schmideg.net/go-ethereum/interface/JavaScript-Console.

Am I looking at a wrong place? Where is the documentation for admin.sleepBlocks?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the docs, but the code in Geth has a two line comment over here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/console/bridge.go#L330

Here's the quote:

```
// SleepBlocks will block the console for a specified number of new blocks optionally
// until the given timeout is reached.
```

Hope that helps!